# Output Markup Inside of Tag Markup

Tags: jekyll, liquid

My question is how can I rewrite this output markup (which does work)

```
{{ forloop.index0 | modulo:4 }}
```

so that it can be used inside of a tag markup  (which doesn't work).

```
{% if forloop.index0 | modulo:4 == 0 %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up working (David helped me get started).

```
{% assign mod = forloop.index0 | modulo:4 %}
{% if mod == 0 %}
    <!-- Do stuff -->
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edited answer :**

For this example I use a custom array, but the array can be **site.pages** or **site.posts** or **site.data.somedatas**.

```
{% assign words = "zero,one,two,three,four,five" | split: ',' %}
```

Then process the **words** array :

```
<ol>
{% for word in words %}

  {% comment %} Here we assign the filtered array to myTest {% endcomment %}
  {% assign myTest = forloop.index0 | modulo:4 %}

  {% comment %} then we process the filtered array {% endcomment %}
  {% if myTest == 0 %}
    <li>
      <h4>Test passing (index = {{ forloop.index0 }} &gt;&gt; modulo = {{ myTest }})</h4>
    </li>
  {% else %}
    <li>
      <h4>test NOT passing (index = {{ forloop.index0 }} &gt;&gt; modulo = {{ myTest }})</h4>
    </li>
  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
</ol>
```

This works on Jekyll 2.2.0, the current Github pages version.

Comment: This actually doesn't work... tried editing it but I couldn't.